# python - Check Raw_input is not empty

Tags: python

I have created the following code as part of an online exercise on codeacademy

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input("what's you name?")

if original != "" and original.isalpha():
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

but then saw later on the course it swapped original != "" to using len(original) > 0

Are they the same as far the interpretter in python cares please?

Answer (score 5):

In your concrete example, `original != ""` and `len(original) > 0` will always give back the same results because we know `original` will always be a string. The latter variant will be a little slower, but you wouldn't notice.

But the whole condition is unnecessary in this context because

```
>>> "".isalpha()
False
```

Therefore, you'd get the *same* logic with

```
if original.isalpha():
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

However, the results would not be correct because

```
>>> "1".isalpha()
False
```

Better use something like

```
if original.isalpha():
    print original
elif not original:
    print "empty"
else:
    print "not alpha"
```